# Ghostscript to compress a batch of PDFs

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, jpeg2000

I have no experience of programming.

My PDFs won't display images on the iPad in PDFExpert or GoodNotes as the images are in JPEG2000, from what I could find on the internet.

These are large PDFs, upto 1500-2000 pages with images. One of these was an 80MB or so file. I tried printing it with Foxit to convert the images to JPG from JPEG2000 but the file size jumped to 800MB...plus it's taking too long.

I stumbled upon Ghostscript, but I have NO clue how to use the command line interface.

I am very short on time. Pretty much need a step by step guide for a small script that converts all my PDFs in one go.

Very sorry about my inexperience and helplessness. Can someone spoon-feed me the steps for this?

EDIT: I want to switch the JPEG2000 to any other format that produces less of an increase in file size and causes a minimal loss in quality (within reason). I have no clue how to use Ghostscript. I basically want to change the compression on the images to something that will display correctly on the iPad while maintaining the quality of the rest of the text, as well as the embedded bookmarks.

**I'll repeat that I have NO experience with command line...I don't even know how to point GS to the folder my PDFs are in...**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really said what it is you want. 'Convert' PDFs how exactly ?

Note that switching from JPX (JPEG2000) to JPEG will result in a quality loss, because the image data will be quantised (with a different quantisation scheme to JPX) by the JPEG encoder. You can use a lossless compression scheme instead, but then you won't get the same kind of compression. You won't get the same compression ratio as JPX anyway no matter what you use, the result will be larger.

A simple Ghostscript command would be:

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf in.pdf

Because JPEG2000 encoding is (or at least, was) patent encumbered, the pdfwrite device doesn't write images as JPX< by default it will write them several times with different compression schemes, and then use the one that gives the best compression (practically always JPEG).

Getting better results will require more a complex command line, but you'll also have to be more explicit about what exactly you want to achieve, and what the perceived problem with the simplistic command line is.

[EDIT]

Well, giving help on executing a command line is a bit off-topic for Stack Overflow, this is supposed to be a site for software developers :-)

Without knowing what operating system you are using its hard to give you detailed instructions, I also have no idea what an iPad uses, I don't generally use Apple devices and my only experience is with Macs.

Presumably you know where (the directory) you installed Ghostscript. Either open a command shell there and type the command `./gs` or execute the command by giving the full path, such as :

```
/usr/bin/gs
```

I thought the arguments on the command line were self-explanatory, but....

The `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite` switch tells Ghostscript to use the pdfwrite device, as you might guess from the name, that device writes PDF files as its output.

The `-o` switch is the name (and full path if required) of the output file.

The final argument is the name (and again, full path if its not in the current directory) of the input file.

So a command might look like:

```
/usr/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o /home/me/output.pdf /home/me/input.pdf
```

Or if Ghostscript and the input file are in the same directory:

```
./gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I want to switch the JPEG2000 to any other format that produces less of an increase in file size and causes a minimal loss in quality (within reason). I have no clue how to use Ghostscript. I basically want to change the compression on the images to something that will display correctly on the iPad while maintaining the quality of the rest of the text, as well as the embedded bookmarks.

Comment: I'd suggest you try the command line in my answer and see how that works for you. If its not acceptable then you'll have concrete things we can discuss and I can (possibly) offer other suggestions, depending on the nature of the problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I have no clue how to execute it. Do I need to move the GS executable to the folder with the PDF? How do I ensure my original file isn't overwritten and the new one has a number or letter added to its name?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! My issue was esoteric enough that I couldn't use the usual forums for it. I'm on Windows. I have a folder of my PDFs on Onedrive. I would like to rename them as they are processed by ghostscript. How do I modify these commands so that it takes a file "ABC.pdf" and renames the output to "ABC new.pdf"?

Comment: Also, what's a "pdfwrite device"? I plan on revisiting all of this and learning it, just don't have the time right now. Plus it could help anyone else who runs into this specific issue.

Comment: Devices are Ghostscript nomenclature. Its various output 'things' are called devices. So there's a PNG device (well several actually, pngalpha, png16m etc), same for TIFF output. For PostScript output there's the ps2write device, which writes PostScript language level 2, etc. The pdfwrite device doesn't have any magic for naming the output file, you need to tell it what you want it to be called. So if you want ABC.new.pdf then you need to specify "-o ABC.new.pdf". You can do shell script programming to do what you want, I think, but I have no expertise in this area on Macs.

Comment: So sorry, I'm still a bit confused. If I want to add a number to original input pdf's filename, how will I use the -o command? Is there an asterix or other character I need to use so it reuses the original name and adds a number to it? I want "File A" to become "File A1", "File B" to become "File B1" and so on.

Comment: There are two 'special' formats available to output filenames, %d and %s. These are the same as the format specifiers to printf in the C language. We'll ignore %s for now. The %d format specifier means 'output every page of the input to a new file, and add the ordinal page number to the filename in place of %d". So for a concrete example; if you have a 10 page PDF file and do "-o out%d.pdf" with pdfwrite, then you'll get 10x1-page files named out0.pdf to out9.pdf.

Comment: You *can't* 'reuse' the original filename, other then by putting that name in the -o switch. To get from an input file named "File A.pdf" to an output file named "File A1.pdf" you need to put -o "File A1.pdf" on the command line. In order to do the kind of thing you are trying to do you need to do it at a higher level, you need to write a shell script as I suggested a couple of comments back. I can't help you with that, because I don't know anything about writing shell scripts on any Apple OS.

Comment: I'm on Windows. Thanks for teaching me! I will give this a shot (after my upcoming exams).

Comment: I'd been assuming an Apple OS since you mentioned an iPad. You could do something like this at the WIndows command shell: " for %s in (*.pdf) do gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o %~ns1.pdf %s" So that looks (in the current directory) for all files with a .pdf extension. It then loads them, one by one, into a variable called %s and calls the Ghostscript command line. The %~ns extracts just the name from the variable %s, then I added a '1.pdf' to the end of that. Finally the %s is used as the input filename for Ghostscript to process.